# Sentinel 3 image offset

Tags: coordinate-system, sentinel-snap, composite, sentinel-3

I am working with Sentinel 3 Data to create monthly composites (LST, NDVI, NDII). I noticed an offset on a few composites (5 out of 32, or all 3 combined: 15 out of 96) (this becomes recognisable e.g. through suddenly parallel running rivers) so I looked through the individual images. First I thought of an error in my processing scripts but after importing the raw data in SNAP and performing:

> "Raster > Geometric > Reprojection > EPSG 4326", as well as: "Raster > Geometric > Mosaic"

there appears an offset/shift in the image.

One misplaced image is: S3B_SL_2_LST____20210203T071601_20210203T071901_20210204T195744_0179_048_334_2880_LN2_O_NT_004

For comparison I used: S3B_SL_2_LST____20210202T074212_20210202T074512_20210203T133325_0179_048_321_2880_LN2_O_NT_004 (this one is fine like most of the others).

Here are some screenshots:

Mosaic in SNAP (you can see the shift to the left)

[image: NDVI_mosaic]

NDVI composite in QGIS (again a shift to the left)
[image: NDVI_compoiste (QGIS)]

This is the original image just after the reprojection in SNAP
[image: S3 image correct]

Here is the misplaced image put on top (you can see the shift to the left)
[image: misplaced iamge]

I noticed this kind of shift in a few other images from different dates as well. What could be the reason behind it? Is this caused by Sentinel 3 itself? Within my research I didn't really find anything and a recurring offset like this should have already caused discussion. However, I could not explain how I am responsible for this error.

(this is the only comparable question I found so far: https://forum.step.esa.int/t/olci-level-1-raw-data-geo-offset-along-greatlakes/39541 I might ask in the step.esa forum as well)

Comment: Opinion-seeking Questions are likely to be closed as *opinion-based*. I suggest you [Edit] the Question to be less discussion-oriented.

Comment: Okay thank you very much